# Calculation of Nutation and Rotation from Pitch and roll (yaw is fixed to 0)

Tags: trigonometry

i am stuck attempting to convert two angles (pitch and roll) to represent tilt within a circle.

Take a plane  $(Z\ \text{(Vertical)}, X\ \text{(Roll)}, Y\ \text{(Pitch)})$

If i have $45$ degrees of roll, $Z$ is $45$ degrees from vertical. If I have $-10$ degrees of Pitch, $Z$ is $-10$ degrees from vertical.

Thats fine, but if I have BOTH $45$ degrees of roll, and $-10$ degrees of pitch, how do i find out how much i have?

The application is an inclinometer. I need to combine pitch and roll angles to show how many degrees from vertical the object is, and in which direction it is leaning. ($0$ degrees up, $90$ degrees right, $180$ degrees down, $270$ left.)   I have been googling for hours and i am sure i have looked straight past the solution but my brain is cooked and i can't find the solution.

Im currently using $Z\ \text{angle} = \sqrt{\text{roll^2} + \text{pitch^2}}$

I think the angle i am looking for is called the angle of nutation??

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Say we have pitch $ = \alpha$ and roll $ = \beta$. I'll assume that both are non-zero.

Start with a vertical line segment $OA$ of length $1$. "Pitch" it to $OB$ and then "roll" it to $OC$. Then we want to find angle $ \gamma$ between $OC$ and the $z$-axis. Using standard trig:

\begin{eqnarray*}
u &=& \cos{\alpha} \\
v &=& u\cos{\beta} = \cos{\alpha}\cos{\beta} \\
\gamma &=& \cos^{-1}v = \cos^{-1}\left(\cos{\alpha}\cos{\beta}\right).
\end{eqnarray*}

We'll measure the direction in which $OC$ is leaning as an anti-clockwise angle from the $x$-axis. That is, angle $\theta$. We have,

\begin{eqnarray*}
s &=& \sin{\alpha} \\
t &=& u\sin{\beta} = \cos{\alpha}\sin{\beta} \\
\theta &=& \tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{t}{s}\right)
 = \tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sin{\beta}}{\tan{\alpha}}\right).
\end{eqnarray*}